# How can I extract the column name when there is a change in the data in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that gets inserted into every night that is a snapshot of the data. At any point in time, the data might change in the columns (AccountNo stays the same, RunKey is incremented by 1, and RunDate increments by 1 day; all other columns can change ad-hoc).  Below is a sample of how the data looks:

```
|AccountNo | RunKey |   RunDate  |     Address     | Salary | PromotionDate|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  12345   |    2   | 06/20/2017 | 123 Main Street | 60,000 |   01/15/2017 |
|  12345   |    3   | 06/21/2017 | 123 Main Street | 60,000 |   01/15/2017 |
|  12345   |    4   | 06/22/2017 | 123 Main Street | 65,000 |   06/21/2017 |
```

Using a LAG function and CASE expression I am able to determine when there is a change (Flag of 1 means it changed):

```
|AccountNo | RunKey |   RunDate  |     Address     |    AddressLAG   |AddressFlag| Salary | SalaryLAG |SalaryFlag| PromotionDate|PromotionDateLag|PromotionFlag|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  12345   |    2   | 06/20/2017 | 123 Main Street | 123 Main Street |     0     | 60,000 |   60,000  |    0     |   01/15/2017 |   01/15/2017   |      0      |
|  12345   |    3   | 06/21/2017 | 123 Main Street | 123 Main Street |     0     | 60,000 |   60,000  |    0     |   01/15/2017 |   01/15/2017   |      0      |
|  12345   |    4   | 06/22/2017 | 123 Main Street | 123 Main Street |     0     | 65,000 |   60,000  |    1     |   01/15/2017 |   06/21/2017   |      1      |
```

I need to insert only the changed records into a new table and the new table will look like this:

```
| RunKey | AccountNo |  ChangedCol   | PrevRunDate |  RunDate   | PrevValue  |  NewValue  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   4    |   12345   |    Salary     | 06/21/2017  | 06/22/2017 |    60,000  | 65,000     |
|   4    |   12345   | PromotionDate | 06/21/2017  | 06/22/2017 | 01/15/2017 | 06/21/2017 |
```

There will be a new record for each column change. So if multiple columns changed, each change would be documented in a new line. This is where I need help, I don't know how to dynamically insert only changed columns into the new table.

Comment: You sure this is how you want to go about rowversioning or auditing changes? You could see this real easy using `except`

Comment: I'm open to ideas. This was just my first thought and no one I work with suggested otherwise. I changed the data to simplify it but I'm working with fees and dates and the problem is our manger may ask why something changed and we have so many records that we can't tell so that's why we are creating this table that tracks any changes so we can go back to any point in time and see where there was a change and what the change was.

Comment: Well you are sort of pivoting the data into a new format for auditing. This may be ok for you, but the question would be what would you use this data for? How would you want to query it. What aggregates / etc would you do on it? Putting it in this format makes it hard to link back to any dataset so that could cause some problems. So the first question is what are you going to do with it. That would help determine if this is a logical approach IMHO

Comment: I updated my commend above but this table is just to keep track of any changes so if we are asked why values changed we can query this table to see what/when something changed.

Comment: In that case you can query the table directly using distinct on all columns excluding the RunKey and Rundate, then self join to the table to the the min(RunDate) and min(RunKey) for that row of data. This would be similar to "only inserting changes" which is a better idea all together. That is, instead of filing that table with rows that haven't changed, only insert when there is a change. That would keep the table size down and eliminate the extra table you are creating. Would that fit the business requirement?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work. As of now, the RunKey ranges from 1 - 50+ and the columns could change anywhere in there and then change back or change to new values and we'd want to track every change and the exact date of change. So if there was a change from RunKey 18 to 19 and then another change from RunKey 34 to 35 we'd want the table to show both changes and the exact RunKey and date that it changed and what columns changed since it may have been different changes each time.

Comment: That's fair on the self join, but what about ONLY inserting updates / changes?

Comment: As a note, I'm just helping out with the SQL side and not in charge of making the decisions. But I was told that the table he inserts into every night will eventually be truncated and only the other table that tracks the changes will remain. He said it won't be used for anything specifically, but rather just a backup or a history of changes he can reference at any time.

Answer (score 1):

So, usually this is done with a trigger. Anytime an insert or update is done on a table, a follow on insert would be done to your audit table. So, I'd really look into that. But if you don't want to go that route or this is a 3rd party system which you can't add triggers, you could just insert changes in a few ways. A quick way is using except. Basically it inserts records from the source table, into the audit table, when they don't match exactly. Here is an example.

```
declare @source table (
                        AccountNo int
                        ,Address varchar(256)
                        ,Salary decimal(16,4)
                        ,PromotionDate datetime)
insert into @source
values
(12345,'123 Main Street',60000,'20170115')


declare @audit table (
                        AccountNo int
                        ,Address varchar(256)
                        ,Salary decimal(16,4)
                        ,PromotionDate datetime
                        ,RunDate datetime)

--load the audit table with the current version of the source table
insert into @audit
select *, getdate() from @source

--show that the tables match currently
select * from @source
select * from @audit

--insert into @audit if there are any changes (notice we haven't made any updates yet)
insert into @audit
select AccountNo, Address, Salary, PromotionDate, getdate() from @source
except 
select AccountNo, Address, Salary, PromotionDate, getdate() from @audit

--show that a record WAS NOT inserted since there was no change. There is only 1 record, the orignal version
select * from @audit

--update the promotion and salary
update @source
set
    PromotionDate = '20170331'
    ,Salary = '65000'

--insert into @audit if there are any changes
insert into @audit
select AccountNo, Address, Salary, PromotionDate, getdate() from @source
except 
select AccountNo, Address, Salary, PromotionDate, getdate() from @audit

--show that a record was inserted since there was a change
select * from @audit
```

Then, all you have to do is select from the @audit table and order by RunDate and you can easily see what was changed quickly, versus pivoting the data and having 1 row for EVERY change for every account. In this example, you only see 1 extra row though there was a salary and promotion data change. You can use your LEAD and LAG functions, or self join on the top 1 where RunDate < RunDate to flag if the column changed but it's really unnecessary.

Comment: Is there a way to capture the old value as well? That's the key here, he wants to know the date of change, the old value, and the new value, as well as which column changed. so instead of inserting the entire row that contains a change, they just want to see the specific column that changed, the date of change, and the old and new values.

Comment: The date of the change is the runDate assuming you run this every day. So you will only get a new row if it changed, and the date will be getdate() which will show the date it changed. Going about it the other way is really taking 4 steps too many. This approach shows you the changes and when it changed, only when it changed. it solves the core problem without having to use a solution for a poor design IMHO

Comment: @bm11 Yes, a trigger can access the  old value as well as the new value.

Answer (score 1):

The following may help, but you will have to define the fields to track in the `Cross Apply`

**Example** or **[dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4e5a93446cd55d8ed1444dabadc45e32)**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([AccountNo] int,[RunKey] int,[RunDate] date,[Address] varchar(50),[Salary] int,[PromotionDate] date)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (12345,2,'06/20/2017','123 Main Street',60000,'01/15/2017')
,(12345,3,'06/21/2017','123 Main Street',60000,'01/15/2017')
,(12345,4,'06/22/2017','123 Main Street',65000,'06/21/2017')


;with cte as (
    Select A.AccountNo
          ,A.RunKey
          ,A.RunDate
          ,B.*
         ,PreValue=Lag(Value)   over (Partition By AccountNo,Item Order by RunDate) 
         ,PreDate =Lag(RunDate) over (Partition By AccountNo,Item Order by RunDate) 
     From  @YourTable A
     Cross Apply ( values ('Address'      ,cast(A.[Address] as varchar(max)))
                         ,('Salary'       ,cast(A.[Salary]  as varchar(max)))
                         ,('PromotionDate',cast(A.[PromotionDate] as varchar(max)))
                 ) B (Item,Value)
)
Select *
 From  cte
 Where Value<>PreValue and PreValue is not null
```

**Returns**

[image]

> **If it Helps with the Visualization**

**The cte Generates**

[image]

Comment: I tested this out with actual sample data and it worked perfectly. I'm testing it with the full data set which is around 900k rows. It's running very slowly since I have 26 columns to track changes and it appears cte0 will make a row for each column per RunKey.

Comment: @bm11 See EDIT-Second Option

Comment: I added your script to a cursor that iterates over the account number and inserts into my table. Works great for all the previous records and will create a trigger going forward. Do you know how to extract the column name using a trigger? When I run the nightly insert I would want it to look at the most recent RunKey at the Account number level and compare to see if any changes occured.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood your requirement clearly but I would have looked for a solution using INSERT / UPDATE triggers to solve this kind of audit-trial tasks. Perhaps that would make things simpler.